# How to get static final variables using JNA

Tags: java, jna, glew

I am using the GLEW library glew32.dll (standard download from the GLEW website) and I am trying to load the variable GLEW_OK. This variable is defined in the glew.h file (as a uint of 0), so I am assuming it would be included in the glew32.dll file. However, when I use the Java JNA code :

```
NativeLibrary glew = NativeLibrary.getInstance("glew.dll");
Pointer p = glew.getGlobalVariableAddress("GLEW_OK");
System.out.println(p.getInt(0));
```

I am given an error of Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up 'GLEW_OK': The specified procedure could not be found.

```
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getGlobalVariableAddress(NativeLibrary.java:587)
at mcclean.opengl.glew.GLEWUtils.init(GLEWUtils.java:22)
```

The library is loaded fine, but it appears the static variable could not be found. Why is the static variable not being loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the header file `glew.h`, `GLEW_OK` is found as such:

```cpp
/* error codes */
#define GLEW_OK 0
```

This is a *preprocessor definition*. This is not a "static final *variable*" as you would conceive in the Java world. When a C++ project is compiled, preprocessor `#define`s are essentially "copypasted" by the preprocessor into the code. This means that `if (val == GLEW_OK)` is literally changed into `if (val == 0)`.

Since the preprocessor simply replaces the text, there is no information about the names or the origins of the values originating from defines in the `.dll` file.

**You need to manually find the values**. You can do this by downloading the binaries from [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and navigating to the `include/GL/glew.h` file. After this, you could create a class for the constants in Java:

```java
class GlewConstants {
    public static final int GLEW_OK = 0;
    // ...
}
```